# Слайдер упорно не хочет вставать на своё место

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, являюсь новичком в данном вопросе поэтому не могу понять в чём же я так косякнул. Слайдер упорно встаёт справа и не хочет вставать по центру, хотя класс вроде задан правильно и больше на него ничего не влияет. Может быть кто-то более опытным глазом сразу распознает ошибку :(

http://youtouch.me.pn/4/ -- слайдер висит справа

UPD: всем огромное спасибо за ответы, к сожалению я не могу еще плюсовать, поэтому просто огромное человеческое спасибо всем !

Answer (score 4):

Уберите у nav float:left;

```
nav {
    /* float: left; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 102px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

или добавьте перед слайдером `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Задайте такие стили слайдеру:

```
.unslider {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Более внимательно расставляйте точки с запятыми в CSS

> /4/css/unslider.css:4
>
> ```
> .unslider {
>     overflow: auto;
>     margin: 0;
>     padding: 0 /*Пропущена точка с запятой*/
>     float:left;
> }
> ```

Если вы хотите выровнять его по центру:

- Установите `margin: auto;`
- Уберите `float`
- Установите `clear` в `left` или `both`